# Is there a way to get effect of adding body to interface method?

Tags: php, interface

Java has default methods, Scala has traits. Is there a way to get the effect that given method in PHP interface has body? Assuming I have total control over the interface, the method, everything.

Comment: You can't, interfaces are empty. But you get abstract classes and traits so you can implement the body there.

Comment: @N.B. PHP does not have traits (AFAIK), abstract class is still a class, so you cannot inherit from several abstract classes (and besides, abstract class can still bring data, instead of behaviour -- unlike interface).

Comment: Well it appears you know everything so let's just leave you like you are.

Comment: PHP has Traits as of 5.4.0 -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: @Erik, THANK YOU! You don't know how happy I am. Could you please, post this as an regular answer (in SO it is not possible to accept comment).

Comment: Sure. But I also think you should clarify the question a bit, because as it stands I'm not sure WHY having traits answers your question. Otherwise it will probably still be closed later.

Comment: @Erik, well, maybe I was too fast, because I am reading now that class `extends` a trait, not `implements` it. I will read some more :-)

Comment: The fact that Scala must do it better (and different) than PHP is that Scala has been designed as a Object Oriented programming language at its core (compared to PHP) and Scala is much more younger and corrects a bunch of "not so well implemented design patterns" such as Singleton and so on. But still, I don't understand in which way traits will help you in your task for what you specified :)

Comment: @Cr3aHal0, interface is usually thought as what implementer has to implement, but it could be also thought as requirement in order to get given behaviour -- for example "if you deliver paint and surface, I will paint it for you", so it is both side contract. Java interface can achieve this, Scala trait also, and I was looking for such way in PHP too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP also has access to Traits as of PHP 5.4.0.

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: Once again, thank you very much! 3 years in the wild, where I have been? :-)

Answer (score 3):

That's the point actually. Interfaces do not implement the body of their methods , that's why you create classes which would implement them.

The purpose of interfaces is to provide an uniform way to interact between classes implementing an interface, but there is nothing that could force their behaviour.

Interfaces represent a specific kind of constraint which is totally different from inheritance

EDIT : I saw your comment but it seems that it was deleted or something. I'm sorry if you felt like i was "paraphrasing"/patronizing what you did say but I can't say more since it's pretty "simple" because of a straight fact

Comment: Short comment -- you answer somebody's else question "what is the interface". I didn't ask that question, so your "answer" is irrelevant here.

Comment: Your question, at first sight, was "can I do this [with  interfaces]" and here was my answer.I don't think it's irrelevant since I just "answered" that what you wanted to do with interfaces wasn't possible because of interface "way of being".

Comment: I am fully aware you cannot add body directly to interface, but there could be a way to achieve THE EFFECT. Take for example C# -- it has similar constraints as PHP, but thanks to extension methods I am able to get similar effect as Scala traits (similar). So for C# problem is solved, I am looking now at PHP.